# What exactly is IIS (Internet Information Services)

Tags: iis

I've read the following about IIS:

> The servers configured with application role support web servers
>   trough IIS Services.

I also know that

> IIS hosts internal and external websites and also web services that
>   communicate through HTTP.

***So I'm trying to figure out what exactly IIS is***: is it a **server** (an application server)? Is it **a collection of web sites and services**? If that's the case, where is it stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Information Server (IIS) is one of the most popular web servers from Microsoft that is used to host and provide Internet-based services to ASP.NET and ASP Web applications. A web server is responsible for providing a response to requests that come from users. When a request comes from client to server IIS takes that request from users and process it and send response back to users.
[image]
Internet Information Server (IIS) includes a set of programs for building and administering Web applications, search engines, and support for writing Web-based applications that access databases such as SQL Server. With IIS, you can make your computer to work as a Web server and provides the functionality to develop and deploy ASP.NET Web applications on the server. You can also set security for a particular Website for specific Users and Computer in order to protect it from unauthorized access.

http://net-informations.com/faq/asp/iis.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byuF0gdqulA

If you want to see the where Files are stored, you can see the inetpub folder on c: drive. In case of SharePoint, configuration files stored on that location but actual content stored in Database.